# Blender 3.0 (or above) texture baking problems

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor, blend-files

I'm having several bugs when trying to bake textures in Blender 3.0 (or any version above that) for quite some time. I thought something was broken in the alpha version, so I kept using Blender 2.93 for baking textures, but those problems persist on the recent stable version as well, so I think there is something wrong with my system or something has changed in the baking process, anyway I didn't find anything online about it.

For example, one of the issues is when baking combined textures, UV Seams end up being visible in the final baked image, even with a bleed margin properly set in the bake settings.

I made this simple file to demonstrate the issue, just a sphere with UV seams marked and UV unwrapped. As shown in the image below, in Blender 3.0 the UV seams are visible in the baked image while using the exact same file for baking in Blender 2.93 results in a proper clean baked image.

Has anyone experienced bugs while baking textures in Blender 3.0?

Could someone please try to open the .blend file below in Blender 3.0 and just simply press "bake" to see if the seams are visible in the baked image?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just got an answer in discord, turning off render denoising in render settings solves the issue. Don't we all like super simple solutions for stupidly annoying problems? yeah

[image]